# How to import nodes in drupal 8?

Tags: nodes, 8, importing-exporting

There are many posts available for migrating the content to D8. But i am not able to understand. I am stopped at some points.

What I have cleared yet?

> Till now there is no UI available node import.
>   Feed module not supporting node import.

What I wants to know?

Is it mandatory to create a custom module to achieve this?
Drush is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Till now there is no UI for importing data included in core.
I also didn't find any module which extends the core with that functionality.

I ended up using the migrate_api which is build in in core and wrote a custom module for my import.
Here is a article how you can achieve that https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/using-the-migrate-source-csv-plugin

But till now I didn't find any solution how I can import the data without having drush installed.

Comment: Getting this error during configuration import --->The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons:

    Configuration block.block.zurb_foundation_account_menu depends on the zurb_foundation theme that will not be installed after import.
    Configuration block.block.zurb_foundation_branding depends on the zurb_foundation theme that will not be installed after import.

Comment: I don't know how you did the import, but try the following: to import just the single migration configuration

Comment: Sorry mistyped. Just import the single migration configuration. If you get an error on the import, please post your configuration.

Comment: is it working if we go for multiple times. Because first time when i import it worked perfectly. But later when i tried showing me this error.

Comment: same configuration shown in the example.

Comment: if you try to import the migration configuration multiple times, you have to add the uuid in the configuration file or delete the whole configuration first. Something like that should work `code`\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('migrate_plus.migration.basics')->delete();`code`

Comment: I just re import my db and start once again and now its working fine. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this module to import node data from CSV file. [Content Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/contentimport)

Answer (score 1):

I had good success importing nodes from another mysql database using migrate_plus: https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus

In there is an example module, migrate_example, that you can use to base your custom module on.

The imports are run through drush.